# DCPROmo Removal on MOSS 2007

Tags: dns, windows-server-2003, sharepoint

In `Windows Server 2003` ruining DCPromo, then installed MOSS 2007, due to DCPROMO error about DNS, I uninstalled DCPrOMO. But this time I can't connect to the server. My problem was the login information, It seems that the domain name has changed. But what is it? Is there a default? The old computer name doesn't work now, the old domain name doesn't work too. 
Please advise .

thanks

Comment: So you made your 2003 server a domain to install MOSS 2007. What was the original computer name, and what was the domain name? What is the computer name now? The computer name should never have changed (have you pulled down the drop-down box when you login?). You may need to just use the "Offline NT Password & Registry Editor" here http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ to remove the password.

Comment: before AD installation my computer name is Intra
after installation of AD i use Zodiac\adminaccount
then uninstall AD
i cant login now using ZOdiac\adminaccount, i cant use also Intra\adminAccount. There is no dropdown in my login page. How can i use the offline NT password and registry editor

Comment: When you hit CTRL+ALT+DEL there is a "Log on to:" box, you will use the administrator account, password, and "Log on to:" drop-down box should say "Intra (this computer)". If it does not say that computer name post back what it says. If you need to remove the password, you will need to make that ultimate boot cd and then run that tool (it will probably be pretty clear what to do).

Comment: It is 2:18 am. I have to go to bed. I will check back in about 5 hours to see how you fared.